# How can I secure Tomcat's webapps with ADFS 2.0 and SAML/SSO?

Tags: tomcat, active-directory, apache2, adfs2.0, shibboleth

I would like to secure my webapps (on Tomcat 5.5) with ADFS SSO. The webapps are accessed from outside through Apache2 and its rewrite module.

There are several steps to make it work (random order):
a. ADFS - ADDS
b. Shibboleth - ADFS
c. Apache2 - Shibboleth
d. XXXXX - Tomcat

Every tutorial is not clear or have many bugs or is out of date, so I have problems with all above steps.
ADFS and ADDS are running on Windows Server 2008 R2
Shibboleth, Apache2, Tomcat are running on Centos 5.5

Please advice how to connect all above technologies.

Here is **Shibboleth config** which work for me:

```
<SPConfig xmlns="urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:native:sp:config"
    xmlns:conf="urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:native:sp:config"
    xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
    xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"    
    xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata"
    clockSkew="180">

    <!--
    By default, in-memory StorageService, ReplayCache, ArtifactMap, and SessionCache
    are used. See example-shibboleth2.xml for samples of explicitly configuring them.
    -->
    <!--
    To customize behavior for specific resources on Apache, and to link vhosts or
    resources to ApplicationOverride settings below, use web server options/commands.
    See https://spaces.internet2.edu/display/SHIB2/NativeSPConfigurationElements for help.

    For examples with the RequestMap XML syntax instead, see the example-shibboleth2.xml
    file, and the https://spaces.internet2.edu/display/SHIB2/NativeSPRequestMapHowTo topic.
    -->

    <!-- The ApplicationDefaults element is where most of Shibboleth's SAML bits are defined. -->
    <ApplicationDefaults entityID="https://centos.my.domain.com/"
                         REMOTE_USER="eppn persistent-id targeted-id" encryption="true" signing="true">

        <!--
        Controls session lifetimes, address checks, cookie handling, and the protocol handlers.
        You MUST supply an effectively unique handlerURL value for each of your applications.
        The value defaults to /Shibboleth.sso, and should be a relative path, with the SP computing
        a relative value based on the virtual host. Using handlerSSL="true", the default, will force
        the protocol to be https. You should also add a cookieProps setting of "; path=/; secure"
        in that case. Note that while we default checkAddress to "false", this has a negative
        impact on the security of the SP. Stealing cookies/sessions is much easier with this disabled.
        -->
        <Sessions lifetime="28800" timeout="3600" checkAddress="false" relayState="ss:mem" handlerSSL="false">

            <!--
            Configures SSO for a default IdP. To allow for >1 IdP, remove
            entityID property and adjust discoveryURL to point to discovery service.
            (Set discoveryProtocol to "WAYF" for legacy Shibboleth WAYF support.)
            You can also override entityID on /Login query string, or in RequestMap/htaccess.
            -->
            <SSO entityID="http://WinServer2008.my.domain.com/adfs/services/trust"
                 discoveryProtocol="SAMLDS" discoveryURL="https://ds.example.org/DS/WAYF">
              SAML2 SAML1
            </SSO>

            <!-- SAML and local-only logout. -->
            <Logout>SAML2 Local</Logout>

            <!-- Extension service that generates "approximate" metadata based on SP configuration. -->
            <Handler type="MetadataGenerator" Location="/Metadata" signing="false"/>

            <!-- Status reporting service. -->
            <Handler type="Status" Location="/Status" acl="127.0.0.1"/>

            <!-- Session diagnostic service. -->
            <Handler type="Session" Location="/Session" showAttributeValues="false"/>

            <!-- JSON feed of discovery information. -->
            <Handler type="DiscoveryFeed" Location="/DiscoFeed"/>
        </Sessions>

        <!--
        Allows overriding of error template information/filenames. You can
        also add attributes with values that can be plugged into the templates.
        -->
        <Errors supportContact="lgrzywacz@xtm-intl.com"
            logoLocation="/shibboleth-sp/logo.jpg"
            styleSheet="/shibboleth-sp/main.css"/>

        <!-- Example of remotely supplied batch of signed metadata. -->
<!--
        <MetadataProvider type="XML" uri="https://WinServer2008.my.domain.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml"
              backingFilePath="federation-metadata.xml" reloadInterval="7200">
            <MetadataFilter type="Signature" certificate="/etc/shibboleth/WinServer2008.my.domain.com.cer"/>
        </MetadataProvider>
-->

        <!-- Example of locally maintained metadata. -->
        <MetadataProvider type="XML" file="metadata.xml"/>

        <!-- Map to extract attributes from SAML assertions. -->
        <AttributeExtractor type="XML" validate="true" path="attribute-map.xml"/>

        <!-- Use a SAML query if no attributes are supplied during SSO. -->
        <AttributeResolver type="Query" subjectMatch="true"/>

        <!-- Default filtering policy for recognized attributes, lets other data pass. -->
        <AttributeFilter type="XML" validate="true" path="attribute-policy.xml"/>

        <!-- Simple file-based resolver for using a single keypair. -->
        <CredentialResolver type="File" key="/etc/pki/tls/private/ca.key" certificate="/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca.crt" password="PASSWORD"/>

        <!--
        The default settings can be overridden by creating ApplicationOverride elements (see
        the https://spaces.internet2.edu/display/SHIB2/NativeSPApplicationOverride topic).
        Resource requests are mapped by web server commands, or the RequestMapper, to an
        applicationId setting.

        Example of a second application (for a second vhost) that has a different entityID.
        Resources on the vhost would map to an applicationId of "admin":
        -->
        <!--
        <ApplicationOverride id="admin" entityID="https://admin.example.org/shibboleth"/>
        -->
    </ApplicationDefaults>

    <!-- Policies that determine how to process and authenticate runtime messages. -->
    <SecurityPolicyProvider type="XML" validate="true" path="security-policy.xml"/>

    <!-- Low-level configuration about protocols and bindings available for use. -->
    <ProtocolProvider type="XML" validate="true" reloadChanges="false" path="protocols.xml"/>

</SPConfig>
```

Here is **Apache config**:

```
#
# Load the Shibboleth module.
#
LoadModule mod_shib /usr/lib/shibboleth/mod_shib_22.so

#
# Used for example logo and style sheet in error templates.
#
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
  <Location /shibboleth-sp>
    Allow from all
  </Location>
  Alias /shibboleth-sp/main.css /usr/share/doc/shibboleth-2.4.3/main.css
  Alias /shibboleth-sp/logo.jpg /usr/share/doc/shibboleth-2.4.3/logo.jpg
</IfModule>

#
# Configure the module for content.
#
# You MUST enable AuthType shibboleth for the module to process
# any requests, and there MUST be a require command as well. To
# enable Shibboleth but not specify any session/access requirements
# use "require shibboleth".
#
<Location />
  AuthType shibboleth
  ShibRequestSetting requireSession 1
  require valid-user
  ShibUseHeaders On
</Location>

<Location /Shibboleth.sso>
        Satisfy Any
</Location>
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName centos.my.domain.com
    ServerAlias www.centos.my.domain.com
    ServerAlias www.centos.ad.xml-intl.com
    ServerAlias centos.ad.xml-intl.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/ca.key

    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} !centos.my.domain.com
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://centos.my.domain.com/$1 [R]
</VirtualHost>
```

I also added **Relying Party Trust** in ADFS 2.0 with these properties:

```
Relying party identifiers = https://centos.my.domain.com/
Display name = Centos
Encryption certificate = this is the ca.crt file mentioned in configs above
Secure hash algorithm = SHA-1
```

I also added **SAML Assertion Consumer Endpoint** with:

```
Binding = POST
Index = 1
URL = https://centos.my.domain.com/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST
```

I'm not sure if i missed something.

Now I have new problem. The browser knows if I logged in, but I need to know who is logged in on the webapp side (there are properties such as **HTTP_EMAIL**, but all these are empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you see the Shibboleth - ADFS step by step guide [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adfs2-step-by-step-guides%28WS.10%29.aspx)?

Answer (score -5):

Ok, I finally did it. Unfortunately MS sites couldn't help. I found the solution after every possible combinations checks.

Comment: anakkin, since you have figured it out, could you post the solution here to help out others with the same trouble?

Comment: Yes... That would be nice.  I'm having trouble just getting the Shibboleth SP to work correctly.